# What can be entered as 'client_credentials' into grant_type field for obtaining access token

Tags: microsoft-translator

What do you mean by 'client_credentials' which are to be entered into grant_type field when obtaining access token for accessing Microsoft Translator API?

Comment: in general oauth2 supports various ways to get an accesstoken, so with the field grant_type you can specify which method you want. the Microsoft Translator API apparently only supports the 'client_credentials' method, but it might be in the future they will add additional methods...

Comment: @Naytzyrhc Thanks for the reply. I was wondering what are my client_credentials? I just have the "Primary Account Key" and "Customer ID" in account information on Microsoft Azure Marketplace.

Comment: It's client_id & client_secret for your app, on how to obtain them please check their documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx